# Publishing Ruby gem to RubyGem.org

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When i am publishing my custom ruby gem to https://rubygems.org using following command

```
   gem push d2w-0.1.0.gem
```

Getting following errors

```
   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SocketError)
   Failed to open TCP connection to mygemserver.com:80 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I want to know why this error is coming and please tell what i am doing wrong

Comment: Examine your `mygem.gemspec` file and change `mygemserver.com` to the name of the gemserver you want to push to (presumably `rubygems.org`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now this is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aleksei mentioned, you should check the gemspec file of your gem.

In your gemspec file you probably find something like (this is the default after generating a gem skeleton):

```rb
spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
```

Then change the spec accordingly as follows:

```ruby
# ...
if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "https://rubygems.org"

  spec.metadata["homepage_uri"] = spec.homepage
  spec.metadata["source_code_uri"] = spec.homepage 
  #spec.metadata["changelog_uri"] = ""
else
  raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
end
# ...
```

Comment: I changed as Aleksei Matiushkin told.